# C# why using reflection get field object, the first field are from child object and then from base class

Tags: c#, reflection

Each object stores base class properties first and then child class properties. But when I try to get object properties with reflection GetFields method I got this result:

```
Int32 j
Int32 i
```

While I expected

```
Int32 i
Int32 j
```

Code sample

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
namespace MyProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Type t = typeof(B);
            FieldInfo[] fields = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            foreach (FieldInfo fi in fields)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fi);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

    class A
    {
        public int i = 1;
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public int j = 2;
    }
}
```

Question: any ideas why GetFields returns properties in different order (which differs from order in which they are stored) ?

Comment: what is your question? what's the output of this code and how does it differ from what you expect/want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does it matter? Your logic shouldn't depend on the order of the returned fields anyway, since it is [*undefined*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The GetFields method does not return fields in a particular order,
>   such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend
>   on the order in which fields are returned, because that order varies.

---

If you want to process `B`'s fields, and you don't care about the base class `A`'s fields, use [`BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Specifies that only members declared at the level of the supplied
>   type's hierarchy should be considered. Inherited members are not
>   considered.

Comment: I asked that question a long time ago when I was a junior software developer and now I realize that the order indeed does not meter and my logic should not depend on that.